# SOAP WebService function returns an array with nusoap instead of xml

Tags: php, arrays, xml, web-services, nusoap

I'm using a commerce server web service that searches orders on our website. The soap response says it is supposed to return xml, however I am getting back a php array which is making parsing the response near impossible.

Is there any flag I can set in nusoap to not have the xml converted to an array?

code i'm using:

```
    $request = $this->client->getProxy();

    $results = $request->SearchPurchaseOrders(['searchClause' => $clause, 'searchOptions' => $options]);

    $guids = [];
    $guids['guid'] = [];

    $results= $results['SearchPurchaseOrdersResult'];
    if(empty($results['diffgram'])) {
        return null;
    }

    $results= $results['diffgram']['NewDataSet']['PurchaseOrders'];

    if(count($results) == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if(isset($results['OrderGroupId'])) {
        $guids['guid'][] = $results['OrderGroupId'];
    } else {
        foreach($results as $result) {
            $guids['guid'][] = $result['OrderGroupId'];
        }
    }

    $orders = $request->GetPurchaseOrdersAsXml(['orderGroupIds' => $guids]);

    echo $orders->response;exit;
```

Comment: Please support your question with code samples. Also, what would be the output of say `print_r($client->response)`

Comment: i edited in code samples. $client->response is empty, however i am getting data back..

Comment: Empty? Did you view the page source code?